# How to access a specific item in a Listbox with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Telerik, HubSection is like Pivot with WP8.

```
<HubSection x:Uid="Section4Header" Header="All note" >
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxobj" Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1"  SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="350" >
                        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton"
                                            Text="Export To PDF"
                                            Click="EditButton_Click"
                                        />
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton1"
                                            Text="Export To PDF syncfu"
                                            Click="EditButton1_Click"
                                        />
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CreateddateTxt" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

C#

```
private void ReadWritePadFileContentList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReadAllWritePadFileContent dbnote = new ReadAllWritePadFileContent();
    DB_ContactList = dbnote.GetAllContacts();//Get all DB contacts 
    if (DB_ContactList.Count > 0)
        deleteAppBarButton.IsEnabled = true;
    else
        deleteAppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;

    listBoxobj.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();//Binding DB data to LISTBOX and Latest contact ID can Display first. 

}
```

listBoxobj is name of ListBox
the problem is So how can I acces the the listbox?

> The name 'listBoxobj' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said, You wont be able to directly access the listbox from the hub's code, as its in a DataTemplate.

**However**, you can create a UserControl eg, `MyUserControl1`.
Put your ListBox inside the `MyUserControl1.xaml` file, and its related c# code in `MyUserControl1.cs` file.
Then, add the user control in your HubSection.

```
<HubSection x:Uid="Section4Header" Header="All note" >
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:MyUserControl1 x:Name="ListControl"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

EDIT: Put your ListBox code inside the `<Grid>` your UserControl code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxobj" Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1"  SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="350" >
                    <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton"
                                        Text="Export To PDF"
                                        Click="EditButton_Click"
                                    />
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton1"
                                        Text="Export To PDF syncfu"
                                        Click="EditButton1_Click"
                                    />
                                </MenuFlyout>
                            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CreateddateTxt" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: can you put an example

Comment: Its already there! Read part after **However**. Now I've added the full code.

To create UserControl, right click on your project inside solution explorer, select Add, select UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that directly as it's within a DataTemplate and your ListBox is therefore generated at runtime.

You might have some joy following the steps in this article to pull your ListBox out of the visual tree: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx